# Cual es mi problema con JOptionPane?

Tags: java

[image: quiero hacer un programa que mustre nombre,apellido, pero no me reconoce JOptionPane. Tampoco cuando hago import java.swing.JoptionPane;]

```
import java.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ejercicio10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombre, apellido1, apellido2;
        nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite su nombre: ");
        apellido1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su primer apellido: ");
        apellido2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su segundo apellido: ");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(nu11, "i ove java");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido! ¿Qué error te indica el IDE cuando pones el cursor encima del import?

Comment: pero como se hace ,solo les pusiste un espacio.

Comment: En concreto el error dice JOptionPane cannot be resolved

Comment: Pero encima del importe dice eso? Que versión de Java usas?

Comment: utilizo eclipse pero es un poco antiguo,eso no deberia importar

Comment: es del 2013 y aunque ya puse nu11 no me sale los mismos errores, tal vez la version es muy antigua

Comment: Revisa que importaste correctamente el JOptionPane
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

Comment: Que mensaje de error muestra ese import java.swing?

Comment: Creo que es por el tipo de variables al estar dentro del public static, tus variables debieran ser String static...

Comment: Además de que no importante correctamente la clase JOptionPane

Comment: Tienes un error topografico, el import correcto es : import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

Comment: gracias Elenasys pues tenias razn ya lo probe y sale bien ahora